# "Homestead Improved" Vagrant VM - Failed to restart php7.0-fpm.service: Unit php7.0-fpm.service not found

Tags: homestead, vagrant-windows

I'm trying to get a **Homestead Improved** Vagrant VM instance running on Windows.
See [Homestead Improved on Github](https://github.com/swader/homestead_improved). I'm following this easy introduction:
https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-get-homestead-vagrant-vm-running/

My steps are:

```
git clone https://github.com/swader/homestead_improved my_project
cd my_project
bin/folderfix.sh
vagrant up
```

Machine boots and is ready. Then provisioner is running. Then I get the follwoing error message:

> **==> default: Failed to restart php7.0-fpm.service: Unit php7.0-fpm.service not found.**
>
> The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
>   assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
>   should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
>   went wrong.

Any hints what to do?

Comment: @Swader's answer should get you squared away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This has been fixed on the repo-level, and should never happen again if you run `git pull` inside your homestead improved cloned folder (but outside of the VM, not SSH-ed into it). If your machine is already running, you *might* have to apply the steps below, too. But new machines (so new clones of Homestead Improved) will not have this happen any more). Explanation of what happened is [here](https://bitfalls.com/en/blog/virtual-cables-homestead-ssh-timeout-and-php7-0-service-not-found).**

@daniel-sixl please try to re-download/re-clone and start from scratch, everything should be working just fine now.

---

Old solution:

Try to change php7.0-fpm to php7.1-fpm - the box was auto-updated to the new version.

You can do this by going into `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and changing the required file - its name will match the site you defined, as per that post you linked. So probably `/etc/nginx/sites-available/homestead.app`.

--

Edit: added more detailed instructions for people very new to it all.

Ok, so what you need to do is, once you're in the sites-available folder, edit the homestead.app file. Something like `sudo vim homestead.app` will do just fine, it'll open a basic text editor (that's quite nightmarish to use when you're new at it, so just be patient :) ) Sudo is important, because you are editing a file that only an admin has access to.

Once you're "in", do the following:

- press `/` (this activates "search") and input `php7.0-fpm`. This should take you to the line which contains that phrase. If you press `/` again and press Enter, that works like "find next", so it'll go to the next line having the phrase, or restart from the top if no other lines contain it.
- when your cursor is on the line with `php7.0-fpm` (you can move it around with arrows of course), press `i`. This activated "insert" mode. Now you can edit the file.
- change the 7.0 to 7.1.
- press ESC to exit edit mode, and go back into read-only mode.
- repeat for each line with 7.0
- once done, while in read-only mode (ESC to make sure), type `:x`. Yeah, like an emoticon with cross lips. Press Enter. That's short for "Save and Exit".
- you will now be in the folder again, from where you should execute `sudo service nginx restart`.

The new configuration should now take effect, and everything should start working.

Comment: Awesome, this was totally correct. I had to force pull though `git fetch --all` then `git reset --hard origin/master` in my ~/Homestead directory. After that `vagrant up --provision` worked for the first time in two days.

Comment: This works for me, but once the machine gets provisioned, I need to repeat the process. Is there a way to make this permanent?

Comment: It should be permanently fixed now if you start over, and for all new future boxes.